# Search and move multiple Outlook folders using vba

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, move, outlook-2007

I need to make some order thru my cases and need to move all the closed ones to a specific folder.
I managed to find a way, sort of, but this solution only moves 1 folder at a time and the thing is there are >200 cases which needs to be moved.
All  the folders are in a shared e-mail account and the way I can identify the folders that needs to be moved is by theirs last 6 characters found in the end of the folder name, which is actually an unique ID. Specifically a folder is named this way: "XX.ddmmyy.string.string.XX.ID"
The only data I have for identifying and moving this folders is a list with IDs which came in a excel file like that:

123456
123457
123458
and so on...

I think what I am searching for is a vector, but don't have much experience with, so could you please help me figure a way to move to insert all the criterias at once to move the folders and to identify the IDs which couldn't be found/moved?

Here is what I have so far (search for the entered ID in the text box, loops thru folders, move it to a specific one and displays a message box).
I run the FindFolder macro.

```
Private myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Private MyFolderWild As Boolean
Private MyFind As String

Public Sub FindFolder()
Dim Name$
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.folder
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim NS As NameSpace
Dim olDestFolder As Object
Dim folder_name As String

Set myFolder = Nothing
MyFind = ""
MyFolderWild = False

Name = "*" & InputBox("Enter the Folder Name that you would like to find:")
If Len(Trim$(Name)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
MyFind = Name

MyFind = LCase$(MyFind)
MyFind = Replace(MyFind, "%", "*")
MyFolderWild = (InStr(MyFind, "*"))

Set Folders = Application.Session.Folders
LoopFolders Folders

If Not myFolder Is Nothing Then
If MsgBox("Do you want to move this folder ?" & vbCrLf &   myFolder.folderPath, vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, "Found your Folder:") = vbYes Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = myFolder
    Set olApp = Application
    Set NS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olDestFolder = NS.Folders("xx@xx.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("cleanup")
    myFolder.MoveTo olDestFolder
Call Repeat
End If
Else
MsgBox "The folder you were looking for can not be found.", vbCritical, "Folder NOT found:"
End If
End Sub


Private Sub LoopFolders(Folders As Outlook.Folders)
Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Found As Boolean

For Each F In Folders
If MyFolderWild Then
  Found = (LCase$(F.Name) Like MyFind)
Else
  Found = (LCase$(F.Name) = MyFind)
End If

If Found Then
  Set myFolder = F
  Exit For
Else
  LoopFolders F.Folders
  If Not myFolder Is Nothing Then Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub


Sub Repeat()
If MsgBox("The folder has been succesfully moved." & vbCrLf & "Do you want to move another folder?", vbQuestion Or vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Call FindFolder
Else
End
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to type the list (of folders to move) in Excel. Then add the following code to Excel

```
Public Sub MoveFolders(rInputRange As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Selection
        rCell.Offset(0, 1) = MoveFolder("*" & rCell)
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Function MoveFolder(sSearchName As String) As Boolean

    Const DESTINATION_FOLDER As String = "linkedin"

    Dim oFoundFolder        As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oDestinationFolder  As Outlook.Folder

    Set oFoundFolder = FindFolderRecursive(sSearchName)

    If oFoundFolder Is Nothing Then
        MoveFolder = False
    Else
        Set oDestinationFolder = FindFolderRecursive(DESTINATION_FOLDER)
        oFoundFolder.MoveTo oDestinationFolder
        MoveFolder = True
    End If

End Function

Public Function FindFolderRecursive(sSearchName As String, Optional oFolder As Folder = Nothing) As Folder

    Dim oSubFolder          As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolders            As Outlook.Folders

    If oFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set oFolders = Outlook.Application.Session.Folders
    Else
        Set oFolders = oFolder.Folders
    End If

    For Each oSubFolder In oFolders
        If LCase(oSubFolder.Name) Like LCase(sSearchName) Then
            Set FindFolderRecursive = oSubFolder
            Exit Function
        Else
            Set FindFolderRecursive = FindFolderRecursive(sSearchName, oSubFolder)
            If Not FindFolderRecursive Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        End If
    Next oSubFolder

End Function
```

Make sure to reference the outlook library.

If you select the list, then you can execute the code for all folders by using the following code in the immediate window

```
MoveFolders Selection
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bas Verlaat! Works perfect! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark the answer so it can be closed ? Thank you